# possible Python integer overflow error

Tags: python, numpy

Below is my code that I'm trying to run to solve for a maximum prioritized product problem i.e. return a maximum value for a product of two numbers in a list. My issue is that the product that is being computed is incorrect when the numbers in the input list are large. I was of the opinion that there will be no integer overflow in error and resulting product will be automatically long but that is not happening evidently as my multiplication is returning some kind of garbage.

```
#"python2"
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun 28 17:12:38 2016

@author: pvatsa
"""
import numpy as np

n = int(raw_input())
alist = np.random.randint(100000, size = n)
print alist
assert(len(alist) == n)
alist = sorted(alist)
print alist
max_no = max(alist)
second_largest_no = alist[n-2]
print max_no*second_largest_no
#print long(product)
#print type(product)
```

Comment: the python version is 2.7 :( not working correctly though

Comment: Well I might have ran pretty bad test case. In theory 100k*100k can overflow int32, so most you can do in this situation is specify dtype for numpy array `alist = np.random.randint(100000, size = n, dtype = 'int64')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.random.randint` will create an array of 32 bits integers:

```
>>> alist = np.random.randint(100000, size = n)
>>> alist.dtype
dtype('int32')
```

Sorting it will preserve that type, creating a list of `numpy.int32` objects instead of converting them back to Python (overflow-safe) integers:

```
>>> foo = sorted(alist)
>>> type(foo[-1])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

As such, the multiplication *can* overflow: you can solve it by either:

- Casting your numbers back to Python numbers
- Having an array of longs in the first place

The first case is simply a matter of converting values of interest:

```
>>> foo[-1] * foo[-2]
1386578402
>>> int(foo[-1]) * int(foo[-2])
9976512994L
```

The second can be done by calling `randint` with `dtype=np.int64` (for numpy >= 1.11) or converting the array afterwards:

```
>>> llist = np.array(alist, dtype=np.int64)
>>> llist.sort()
>>> np.prod(llist[-2:])
9987503750
```

Comment: Thanks @val. It makes complete sense. Also the minute I replaced numpy object creation with python raw_input function to generate the list `a = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]` , everything became overflow-safe and i got the desired result.